# How to read a dictionary from a file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, file, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a problem with keeping user totals in Python.  I've searched and tried many things, but with no success which brings me here.  I want to be able to store user totals in a file and retrieve them as needed.  I have been `json.dump()` the info in and I tried `json.load()` but I am not able to retrieve one specific value like if I wanted to know what balance user2123 had, not everyone.  So basically, I need to know what to call the json.load so I can do `nameofdictionary[user2123]` and get their balance. I don't think my current code would help any, but if you need it, just let me know.  Thanks a bunch!

```
#gets the username
combine=[{str(signup):0}]
json.dump(combine,open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Balances.txt','a'))
#stuff that doesn't matter
print 'Withdrawing %s dollars... '%howmuchwd
json.load(open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt'))
print 'You now have %s dollars' %Idkwhattocallit
```

The file looks like this:
[{"12": 0}][{"123": 0}]

Comment: Can you post a longer code sample? Can we see `json.dump()` and `json.load()` in context?

Comment: What's the problem with `print json.load(myfile)['user2123']` ?

Comment: what are user totals? total number of users or a list of users?

Comment: Sorry!  The user totals are the amount of money each user has.  Sorry I should have been more clear.

Comment: @timgeb I am going to try that quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the return-value (a dictionary) of `json.load` to a variable. Actually you are not doing anything with the return value :)

You can do

```
d = json.load(open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt'))
print d['user2123']
```

Or if you don't need the dictionary after checking 'user2123':

```
print json.load(open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt'))['user2123']
```

Demo-file `Database.txt`:

```
{"userXYZ":"3.50", "user2123":"42"}
```

Python-Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('Database.txt') as f:
...     print(json.load(f)['user2123'])
... 
42
```

Edit:

Sorry, I overlooked this issue: The content of your file

```
[{"12": 0}][{"123": 0}]
```

is **not** valid JSON. Valid JSON would look like this:

```
{"12": 0,"123": 0}
```

Assuming that's the content of your file:

```
>>> with open('Database.txt') as f:
...     print(json.load(f)['123'])
... 
0
```

Comment: I get this error:   `File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    json.load(open('C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Database.txt'))['12']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 15 - line 1 column 34 (char 14 - 33)`

Comment: @user3818089 in that case, your `Database.txt` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok I got it.  It was a mistake on my end with having the dictionary surrounded by [] and {}. Thanks so much!